# Python: what is the best way to iterate through a dataset to pass the values into a dict?

Tags: python, google-dfp

I have a function that sends data to my ad server via the Google DFP API. The function works when my variables (order_id, targeted_placement_id, etc..) have the data hard-coded to it.

My data comes from *'ad_data.csv'* where each column is the key and the data in the associated row is the value. I want to loop through this dataset and pass the values of each row inside the csv file into the correct value inside the `line_item` dict.  Below is my pandas `DataFrame.head()`

```
        order_id   targeted_placement_id          campaign
  0   3494982232              5555666677     Ad Campaign 1
  1   8494984434              1112666177     Ad Campaign 2
  3   4494922232              0992666677     Ad Campaign 3
  4   1494984234              9494939499     Ad Campaign 4
```

---

However, inside the for loop, I want to pass each row  *'ad_data.csv'*

```
from googleads import dfp
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ad_data.csv')
order_id = df['order'].tolist()
targeted_placement_id = df['placement_id'].tolist()
campaign_name = df['campaign'].tolist() 

def main(client, order_id, targeted_placement_ids, campaign_name):
     line_item_service = client.GetService('LineItemService')

     # Create line item objects.
     line_items = []
     for _ in range(1):
         line_item = {
             'orderId': order_id,
             'name': campaign_name,
             'targeting': {
                 'inventoryTargeting': 
                    {'targetedPlacementIds': targeted_placement_ids},
             }
          }
          line_items.append(line_item)

     line_items = line_item_service.createLineItems(line_items)

     for line_item in line_items:
         print('Target id "%s", in order id "%s", named"%s" was created' 
               %(line_item['targetedPlacementId'], line_item['orderId'], line_item['name']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dfp_client = dfp.DfpClient.LoadFromStorage()
    main(dfp_client, order_id, targeted_placement_id, campaign_name)
```

---

If done correctly, `line_item` should print:

```
Target id 5555666677 in order id 3494982232, named Ad Campaign 1 was created 
Target id 1112666177 in order id 8494984434, named Ad Campaign 2 was created 
Target id 0992666677 in order id 4494922232, named Ad Campaign 3 was created
Target id 9494939499 in order id 1494984234, named Ad Campaign 4 was created
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: so you want `order_id` to be the values in a file?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to take a table from a CSV (or JSON) file and basically load that into a table in memory in a Python script.  I see that you want a `list` of `dict`s to represent your internal table.  Is that a hard requirement?  If not, you're probably better off with a Pandas DataFrame, which has a nice function to load a CSV file directly into a DataFrame: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv).  It also supports JSON: [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html).

Comment: @SuperStew I want order_id, targeted_placement_id, and campaign to be values from a file.

Comment: So why not read them into a list and then loop through it under your `if __name....` statement?

Comment: @SuperStew When I loop through the list, I am having trouble passing one value at a time into my `line_item` dict. I have a feeling that I am missing a step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with *.csv* and *.json* files you should be using the pandas lib.

To read the file you can use [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), it will return a pandas **DataFrame** object which you can manipulate and then if you want to save it as a .csv file just use [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

To access a specific row or column you can use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

You can also convert a **Series** to a python list with [tolist()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html)
*e.g.*

```
DF = pandas.DataFrame.read_csv('filename.csv')
orders = DF['Orders'].tolist()
```

*orders is a python list with the values from the column named Orders from your .csv file*

**Edit:**
As discussed in the comments, you should figure out which tool suits best to your problem. But if you plan to work with a large dataset I recommend you to read about pandas memory usage in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#gotchas)

Interesting article: [reducing memory usage with pandas for large datasets](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/)

**Edit 2:**

To get each column of your **DataFrame** as a list you should do:

```
orders = DF['order_id'].tolist()
targets = DF['targeted_placement_id'].tolist()
campaigns = DF['campaign'].tolist()
# print(orders, targets, campaigns)
```

The **ValueError** you are getting is because you are trying to pass these lists as values to your dictionary's keys `orderId`, `name` and `targetedPlacementIds`. One way to iterate over these lists is with `enumerate(orders)` it will return an index and the order_id of each position.

*e.g.*

```
0   3494982232
1   8494984434
2   4494922232
```

And then to get the `campaigns` and `targets` of each order, you just pass the lists with the order index, so your loop will be something like this:

```
# Create line item objects.
line_items = []
for index, order in enumerate(orders):
    line_item = {
        'orderId': order,
        'name': campaigns[index],
        'targeting': {
            'inventoryTargeting': {
                'targetedPlacementIds': targets[index]
            }
        }
    }
    line_items.append(line_item)
print(line_items)
```

finally, your `line_items` will be a list where each position is a dictionary.

**PS:**

Your printing loop has an error, instead of `line_item['targetedPlacementId']` it should be `line_item['targeting']['inventoryTargeting']['targetedPlacementIds']`

You can also check if your DataFrame has null values with:

```
if DF.isnull().values.any():
        raise Exception('Null values')
```

Comment: i wouldn't advocate for pandas unless it's some really large data or it needs a lot of processing. Just using the built in csv/json modules is usually a lot faster for "small" data.

Comment: Thanks @SuperStew, this is a good observation, but in the question he did not mention the data size. If its not a big dataset then the simpler the better.

Comment: It also depends on how he plans to use the data.  It's very possible that performance is not important.  Does the functionality / ease-of-use provided by Pandas outweigh the hit to performance?  That is something that the OP would need to consider.  Without understanding more about his use case, we shouldn't make sweeping generalizations about whether Pandas or the built-in libraries are better suited to his problem.

Comment: using `read_csv` worked great to get through the dataset (it is quite large). However, I am trying to pass in one item at a time from the `orders` list into the `line_item` dict but I get this error _in _wrapper self.__class__.__name__)) ValueError: The String type doesn't accept collections as value__. My guess is I am passing the entire `orders` list into the `line_item` but can't quite figure out what I need to do to solve the problem. Sorry if I am not being clear as I am a bit confused on the next steps.

Comment: @CameronShannon Could you please update your code and show the DataFrame with `DF.head()`? `orders` is a list of a single column named Orders so each position stores a String and your `line_item` is a dictionary

Comment: @RenanLopes made quite a few edits to my question and code. Hopefully this time around I am more clear. My initial question was rather confusing :)

Comment: @CameronShannon Updated answer. I hope it helps :)

Comment: @RenanLopes Excellent! Thanks for the update- I was never thought to use enumerate. Very helpful!